# Epsilon delta proof : $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}e^\frac{-1}{x^2}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

i've been unsuccessful with attempting this epsilon delta proof.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}e^\frac{-1}{x^2}=0$

So far i've been attempting to utilize the following inequalities for an upper bound from my textbook:

$1+x\leq e^x \leq \frac{1}{1-x}$ and the fact that $a \leq b \leq c$ $\rightarrow$ $\lvert b\rvert \leq \lvert a\rvert + \lvert c\rvert$.

i then get the following:

$\lvert e^\frac{-1}{x^2} \rvert \leq \lvert \dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}} \rvert + \lvert - \dfrac{1}{x^2} \rvert+1$

But i can't seem to move on from here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $y\text{}$? The exponential function is always positive, you do not need that awkward inequality.

Comment: sorry. I've edited the post regarding the y. Could you elaborate further on how i could solve this then? Thanks.

Comment: You wanna sandwhich it between two functions whose limit is $0$. I.e., $f(x),g(x)$ such that $f(x) \leq e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\leq g(x)$.. ofc with $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=0$.

Comment: ahh the squeeze theorem. Thanks, i'll utilize that.

Comment: Yeah, I cant think of two functions off top of my head, but the values are always less than $\sin x$ or above $\sin x$.. and $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x=0$..namely, the graph of $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ is a *subset* of the graph of $\sin x$..

Comment: For every $z>0$, $\mathrm{e}^{z}>1+z$, i.e., $\mathrm{e}^{-z}<\frac{1}{1+z}$. Thus, for $x\ne 0$, $\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}<\frac{1}{1+1/x^2}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$. Obviously, $\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}>0$.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1821084/42969.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ s.t.
$$|x| < \delta \implies \big|e^\frac{-1}{x^2}\big| < \epsilon$$

Suppose $|x| < \delta$,

$$\begin{align}
|x| < \delta &\implies x^2 < \delta^2 \\
&\implies \frac{1}{x^2} > \frac{1}{\delta^2} \\
&\implies \frac{-1}{x^2} < \frac{-1}{\delta^2} \\
\end{align}$$

and since $e^x$ is a monotonically increasing function the result above implies that

$$e^\frac{-1}{x^2} < e^\frac{-1}{\delta^2}$$

and since $e^x$ is always positive we can see that

$$\big|e^\frac{-1}{x^2}\big| < e^\frac{-1}{\delta^2}$$

now determining $\delta$ is just a matter of solving the equation

$$e^\frac{-1}{\delta^2} = \epsilon$$

which gives us

$$\delta = {1 \over \sqrt{-\ln \epsilon}}$$

you can also see that this function for $\delta$ is not defined at $\epsilon \ge 1$ so we need to find a $\delta$ for cases where $\epsilon \ge 1$ which turns out to be trivial since the function $e^\frac{-1}{x^2}$ is always less than $1$ so any positive value for $\delta$ would work, we can choose an arbitrary value like $1$ for example.

Thus our $\delta$ can be

$$\begin{align}
\delta = \begin{cases}
{1 \over \sqrt{-\ln \epsilon}} & \epsilon < 1 \\
1 &\epsilon \ge 1 \\
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$